# Как скрыть бесконечный батник?

Tags: cmd, bat

Написал простенький **зацикленный батник** - запрещает создавать в определённой папке файлы конкретного расширения, то есть работает по принципу наподобие этого:

```
@echo off
for /l %%переменная in (0) do if exist *.расширение (del *.расширение)
```

При его запуске открывается пустое окно cmd, вечно мозолящее глаза и в принципе мешающее, допустим, мисскликами по нему в панеле задач. Есть ли способ *не запускать/скрыть это назойливое окошко*, например, через какой-то атрибут команды start в другом батнике?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: на SO есть ответы как запустить батник скрытно. Например, через VBscript. Можно и на скорую руку через сервисы. Например, создать сервис "mycmd". Минус в том, что он (сервис) не будет правильно реагировать на запросы остановки. Надо будет "убивать" порождаемый процесс, кроме этого для управления им потребуются права админа. Пример создания :  sc create mysmd binpath= "cmd /K start my.bat" type= own